# Ramdom freeze on ubuntu 16.04.02 with ATI HD 7850

Tags: 16.04, kernel, freeze

### Problem

I switched from Nvidia Quadro k620 to ATI Radeon HD 7850, and the ATI works nicely, except for random freezes. From syslog:

```
Feb 21 16:42:34 kvmhost kernel: [14207.534328] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
Feb 21 16:42:34 kvmhost kernel: [14207.534339] DMAR: INTR-REMAP: Request device [[00:00.1] fault index 4
Feb 21 16:42:34 kvmhost kernel: [14207.534339] INTR-REMAP:[fault reason 38] Blocked an interrupt request due to source-id verification failure
Feb 21 16:42:34 kvmhost kernel: [14207.534345] DMAR: INTR-REMAP: Request device [[00:00.0] fault index 2
Feb 21 16:42:34 kvmhost kernel: [14207.534345] INTR-REMAP:[fault reason 38] Blocked an interrupt request due to source-id verification failure
Feb 21 16:42:52 kvmhost kernel: [14225.947331] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 202
Feb 21 16:42:52 kvmhost kernel: [14225.947343] DMAR: INTR-REMAP: Request device [[00:00.1] fault index 4
Feb 21 16:42:52 kvmhost kernel: [14225.947343] INTR-REMAP:[fault reason 38] Blocked an interrupt request due to source-id verification failure
```

### Attempted fix

I searched Google for DMAR, and [a page about Intel-IOMMU on kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/Intel-IOMMU.txt) said to disable "igfx" by using `intel_iommu=igfx_off`. The symptoms are still there, though.

I followed the Intel-IOMMU page and tried to report a bug, but they replied and said to ask here.

### System information

- Install Version: Ubuntu 16.04.2
- `uname -a`: `Linux kvmhost 4.4.0-64-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:50:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

If you need more information then please let me know. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Define freeze! Can you change to VT? Log in with SSH? Which video driver? What is xorg.conf?

Comment: http://www.evernote.com/l/AIl-Zu7VFUNN7aqLzTU5EJUh19Lq0hxp9bk/

Could check above link?
I answered your question.

Thanks for your effort..

Comment: I think it is solved.
pci=nomsi, I added it to grub.

sudo vi /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nomsi"

After that, the freeze disappear.

Thanks for your effort.