# Freezes in 20.04.2. No idea how to troubleshoot

Tags: 20.04, pycharm

I'm brand new to Linux and Ubuntu and need a little help. I'm running 20.04.2 and frequently my system freezes up completely. I have zero knowledge of how to troubleshoot this problem. So far to restart I have been using Alt+PrtScrn+REISUB. Normally if I'm playing music on spotify it will continue despite everything else having frozen.

EDIT: I seem to have the most problems when running PyCharm.

EDIT2:
[This is my `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhM0o.png)

Comment: Since you can use the SysRq keys (REISUB) to tell the system to safely reboot; you know the linux kernel is up & working as you can give it the command REISUB & it is responding. As a clean shutdown occurred, you can search systemd logs (`journalctl`) to look for clues; as they survive reboot (`dmesg` messages do not). I'd also try using Ctrl+Alt+F4 to switch to a text terminal & try logging in.. This will allow exploration of the system before rebooting, and allow you to test theories on why it's freezing, also it'll tell you only the GUI is freezing.

Comment: Do you have enough RAM? Consider setting up swap, upgrading your RAM, or switching to a lighter distribution like Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu freezes randomly with audio playing in the background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247855/ubuntu-freezes-randomly-with-audio-playing-in-the-background)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Very beginner question coming up - how can I tell if I'm running out of RAM? The PC I'm using has 8GB.

Comment: Open System Monitor when you run PyCharm, and you can see the amount of RAM being used. 8 GB is otherwise more than enough to run Ubuntu, unless PyCharm consumes too much RAM.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @guiverc Ctrl+Alt+F4 didn't work.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi It says that PyCharm is using 1GB of RAM.

Comment: @heynnema Included in the question the info you're looking for.

Comment: @Rwzfs Status please...

Answer (score 0):

Your 2G /swapfile is too small. Let's increase it from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: Just did this. The swap has worked in that it increased from 2G to 4G, just waiting now to see if it fixes the freezes. Will update later today to see.

Comment: Increasing to 4GB still had freezes. Upped it to 11 and still have had freezes.

Comment: @Rwzfs Reduce your swap back down to 4G. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: Bios version 7.11. Motherboard is Foxconn 2ABF. @heynnema

Comment: @Rwzfs Is this a HP computer? If so, give me the model # for that. I'm having trouble finding the proper BIOS update for you.

Comment: It's a computer I've built, but it shows a HP splash screen when I turn it on. Is it a model# for a specific part?

Comment: @Rwzfs Sounds like your motherboard came from a HP computer, but without a HP model #, I can't find the BIOS update for it at https://support.hp.com. The Foxconn web site isn't helpful either. You may have to do some research on your own to try and find it.

Comment: @Rwzfs Did you reboot after increasing the /swapfile size?

Comment: Hmm okay I'm not sure how I'll be able to find it, I'll do some digging. Pretty sure I did, but I can try again. Should I increase the swapfile size back to ~11G? I read someone else say to put it as 1.5x your RAM.

Comment: @Rwzfs No, swap at 4G is more than enough. (1.5 x RAM) is very old school thinking. Try this... at the GRUB menu, choose Additional Options, and select an older kernel to boot from, and see if there's any improvement.

Answer (score -1):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: So when I input `man mkswap swapon fstab` I get a big block of text and I'm not quite sure what to do next. I put a photo in the main question that shows my swap space to be 2GB, should I then make this 8GB? How do I go about doing this?