# Video freezing, audio continues. Must hard restart to fix

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video, freeze

I am having an issue where the video on the screen will freeze up, though audio continues just fine. This happens most often when I am launching a program, but has also happened completely randomly, or on minimizing or opening windows. There does not seem to be any reproducible steps to cause this issue so that I can troubleshoot through it. I have to just wait for it to happen. After every time it happens the only way I can get back to using my computer is to fully hard reset it with holding the power button. I have tried checking the logs (which have horrible time stamping), and in particular waiting several minutes before turning it back on so I could hopefully use timestamps to find where the error may have occurred. I have tried searching logs for "error" or "fail", and nothing seems to jump out at me as any kind of critical video-stopping error.

My suspicion is that it has something to do with Nvidia drivers. I am using an RTX2060 with the proprietary Nvidia drivers. I have tried other ones, including the open source once, and the problem still persists. I am ruling out hardware malfunction because the computer operates perfectly on the Windows hard drive.

Finally, I have tried scouring AskUbuntu, several Discords, and Reddit. Every time I ask for help it is met with resounding silence, or I cannot find anything that was able to resolve. I am not even particularly looking for someone to hold my hand through this ordeal and troubleshooting. I am just looking for advice on how to read these logs better, or maybe even more robust logging software that may help determine what is going on. If this is something incredibly common and easy to fix please do help. I will admit to being bad at finding answers online if that's the case.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; and if you're using a Ubuntu LTS release - what kernel stack option you chose to use. You've provided no application details; nor setup details that may contribute/help the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu freezes randomly with audio playing in the background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247855/ubuntu-freezes-randomly-with-audio-playing-in-the-background)